# Apache ProxyPassMatch match paths including top level domain

Tags: regex, apache, http, reverse-proxy

I have two Domains

1. api.myorg.host
2. api.myorg.com

How do I match based the toplevel domain and its path. I have tried following, but does not work.

config1.conf

```
ProxyPassMatch ".host/v2/test(.*)" "https://api.myorg-one.com/v2/test$1" nocanon
ProxyPassReverse ".host/v2/test(.*)" "https://api.myorg-one.com/v2/test$1" nocanon
<LocationMatch ".host/v2/test(.*)">
        Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</LocationMatch>
```

config2.conf

```
ProxyPassMatch ".com/v2/test(.*)" "https://api.myorg-two.com/v2/test$1" nocanon
ProxyPassReverse ".com/v2/test(.*)" "https://api.myorg-two.com/v2/test$1" nocanon
<LocationMatch ".com/v2/test(.*)">
        Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</LocationMatch>
```